# Full featured ASP.Net gridview from dynamic crm data source

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

I've only succeed in making a ASP.NET GridView that connects to the SQL Server in which the Dynamic CRM data resides, however connecting directly to the database only enables me to only view the records without doing any operation in it. (Actually, I *can* do CRUD operation, however I believe it isn't considered to be safe to directly updating or inserting data directly to the database in the case of Dynamic CRM Application, CRUD operation should be done through the Web Service).

Is it possible to build a full featured ASP.net GridView that connects to Dynamic CRM Data Source, in which it can do Insert, Select, Update, and Delete (CRUD Operation)? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution/approach so that when I'm do update/delete/insert in the GridView, I'll call the Dynamic CRM Web service in the back end to do so.

Comment: What you're looking for is some kind of API I guess...

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The CRM SDK has all CRUD operations for all entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It is possible, in the end I just use ObjectDataSource for the GridView, in which I populate the Objects using the Dynamic CRM SDK.